# First Success distribution PMF sum problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, summation

I have the following problem:

> Each toss of a coin results in a head with probability $p$. The coin is tossed until the first head appears. Let $X$ be the total number of tosses (including the count of the first head appears).
>
> What is $P(X < m)$ for $m = 1,2, \dots$?

It is important to clarify that, in this context, the variable $X$ is said to have the *first success* distribution (which is defined to include the toss of the first success), as opposed to the Geometric distribution (which is defined to exclude the toss of the first success). Therefore, if have that $X \sim \text{FS}(p)$ and $Y \sim \text{Geom}(p)$, then $P(X =  Y + 1 = k) = P(Y = k - 1) = (1 - p)^{k - 1} p$ for all tosses $k = 1, 2, \dots$, since the PMF for Geometric random variables is $(1 - p)^k p$.

I have that

$$P(X < m = 1) = 0$$

and

$$\begin{align} P(X < m = 2, 3, \dots) &= \sum_{k = 1}^{m - 1} (1 - p)^{k - 1}p \\ &= p + (1 - p)p + \dots + (1 - p)^{m - 2} \\ &= p(1 + (1 - p) + \dots + (1 - p)^{m - 2})\end{align}$$

The solution has that

> $$\begin{align} P(X < m = 2, 3, \dots) &= \sum_{k = 1}^{m - 1} (1 - p)^{k - 1}p \\ &= p + (1 - p)p + \dots + (1 - p)^{m - 2} \\ &= p(1 + (1 - p) + \dots + (1 - p)^{m - 2}) \\ &= p\dfrac{1 − (1 − p)^{m−1}}{1 - (1 - p)} \\ &= 1 − (1 − p)^{m−1} \end{align}$$

How did the author get that $p(1 + (1 - p) + \dots + (1 - p)^{m - 2}) = p\dfrac{1 − (1 − p)^{m−1}}{1 - (1 - p)} = 1 − (1 − p)^{m−1}$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a finite geometric series, and finite geometric series can be easily summed:
$$a+ar+\dots+ar^n=a\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$
Thus
$$1+(1-p)+\dots+(1-p)^{m-2}=\frac{1-(1-p)^{m-1}}{1-(1-p)}$$
and the result follows.

Comment: What you're describing here doesn't explain how the author got $p(1 + (1 - p) + \dots + (1 - p)^{m - 2}) = p\dfrac{1 − (1 − p)^{m−1}}{1 - (1 - p)}$ and then that $p\dfrac{1 − (1 − p)^{m−1}}{1 - (1 - p)} = 1-(1-p)^{m-1}$

Comment: And if this is a finite geometric series, how does one solve it?

Comment: @ThePointer You should have known the formula for summing a finite geometric series _before_ reading this.

Comment: @ThePointer In fact most derivations of the formula for the infinite geometric series go through the finite case first, then take the limit. Multiply the finite series by $r$. Then subtract from the original finite series. What do you get?

Comment: I apologise. My confusion stems from the fact that my textbook never defines a finite geometric series, and actually defines a geometric series as the infinite case, with no mention of the finite case at all.

Comment: Wikipedia lists ${\displaystyle a+ar+ar^{2}+ar^{3}+\cdots +ar^{n-1}=\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}ar^{k}=a\left({\frac {1-r^{n}}{1-r}}\right)}$ as the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum

Comment: @ThePointer Corrected.

Comment: Ahh, ok, my textbook *does* indeed have this, but it has it has it listed, confusingly, as the *$n$th partial sum of the geometric series*.

Comment: Any idea how the author got $p\dfrac{1 − (1 − p)^{m−1}}{1 - (1 - p)} = 1-(1-p)^{m-1}$?

Comment: @ThePointer Algebraic simplification.

Comment: Hmm, but how exactly?

Comment: @ThePointer $1-(1-p)=p$

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you very much for all of the help!!!